# Apache and Symbolic Symlink getting parent dir php

Tags: php, apache, symlink

i have a problem creating symlink, i want the script take the "child" folder instead of the parent folder

```
/var/www/FolderParent - .... somefile.php
/var/www/FolderChild  - .... somefile.php (symlink from parent)
```

somefile.php content:

```
echo "DIR:".dirname(__FILE__);
```

show :

```
DIR: /var/www/FolderParent
```

expected:

```
DIR: /var/www/FolderChild
```

my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

permissions of FolderParent and FolderChild both has apache user and group "www-data", and for testing purpose all the files are on 777

how can I set apache to take the child path?, the idea of doing that is to have a single instance that will be used in several sites, and be able to update just the single instance

note:  I can not change the code of the scripts because is base on a CMS, so it means to change all the CMS

edit: I also tried with hard link but, i can't perform this on folders

Answer (score 0):

Create a hard link instead of a symbolic link.

Comment: i did it, but i also has some folders , and i can't make hard link on folders